# OAuth2 different token expiration time per client

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using [spring-security-oauth2](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth) to implement my OAuth2 Authorization server. spring-security-oauth2 is going away and I understand I need to replace it with [spring-authorization-server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server)

**Question:**
Is it possible to have different token-expiry-time for different clients (here client represents client-id/client-secret pair)?

If Yes, can you please share documentation/sample code around `spring-authorization-server`?

If no, is it a limitation of spring-authorization-server OR it is not allowed by OAuth2 spec?

(To clarify, I am NOT saying that it was possible in spring-security-oauth2, if it was I would like to know as well)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can have different expiration times per client. You would use the `tokenSettings` of each `RegisteredClient`, as in the following example:

```java
RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(2))
                        .build())
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();
```

See the [sample config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java) for full context.

Comment: Could you clarify the difference here between the client id/secret of the registered client and the client id/secret that will be used for the client credentials grant flow? I've been searching for a distinction without luck.

Comment: Sorry @Scott, I'm not sure I understand. I don't believe there is a distinction.

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  I was confused as I didn't realise that the registered client and client credentials are the same.  I think this is in part because I've yet to see an example of a non-authenticated registered client for a public API that uses the authorization code and refresh grant flows only.

Comment: Gotcha. FYI we're actually working on public client samples and a [webinar](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) on March 10, 2022 on that topic. In the meantime, [here's an example `RegisteredClient`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/c799261a72b5d2f345afbcce920390473651f53d/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/TestRegisteredClients.java#L57-L66) for a public client. Note that refresh tokens are not issued in that case.